# accessing keys/values in JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json

In java I have the following code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("firstKey", new JSONObject());
```

Now in the new object corresponding to the key "firstKey", I want to start inserting new key-value pairs, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried `oppJSON.get("firstKey").put("one","two");` but this doesn't work - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try ```obj.get("firstKey").put("one","two")```

Comment: sorry that was a typo in the question that I've fixed - when I do that it says "Cannot resolve method 'put' in 'Object'"

Comment: use ```getJSONObject``` instead of ```get```

Comment: can you add which library you are using?

Comment: I will prefer to use Gson always while manipulating the json objects. Give it a try. It will make your code more readable and maintainable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject have specific get methods like `getString`, `getInt`, `getDouble` etc. In your case, you need `getJSONObject`

```java
oppJSON.getJSONObject("firstKey").put("one","two");
```

Answer (score -1):

Class `JSONObject` implements a `Map` without generics. So while you can use `Map<String, String>`, `JSONObject` is the equivalent of `Map<Object, Object>`. Everything pulled out of it using `get` has to be cast to its type.

Try `((JSONObject)obj.get("firstKey")).put("one", "two")`